# How can I remove ALL duplicates from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

First of all, I'd like to point out to all you duplicate question hunters that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php) does not fully answer my question.

Now, I've got an array. We'll say that the array is `array(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2)`

I need to remove the duplicates. Not just one of the duplicates, but *all*, so that the result will be `array(1, 4)`

I looked at [array_unique()](http://us.php.net/array-unique), but that will only result in `array(1, 2, 3, 4)`

Any ideas?

Comment: you could disambiguate your question by changing it to: "How can I remove duplicates, _and the values duplicated_, from an array?"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the combination of [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique), [`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/array_diff_assoc) and [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff):

```
array_diff($arr, array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr)))
```

Comment: +1 for ingenuity, though it's hard to read the intent when you see a line like that!

Comment: this is significantly slower than Ciprian's approach though, I just did a quick benchmark and this is 4x slower. A little surprising.

Answer (score 8):

```
function removeDuplicates($array) {
   $valueCount = array();
   foreach ($array as $value) {
      $valueCount[$value]++;
   }

   $return = array();
   foreach ($valueCount as $value => $count) {
      if ( $count == 1 ) {
         $return[] = $value;
      }
   }

   return $return;
}
```

Comment: The first loop could more efficiently be replaced by $arrayCount=array_count_values($array)

Comment: Thanks. I think the algorithm is important as well. Someone has already posted a solution using native PHP functions.