# How can I remove all duplicates so that NONE are left in a data frame?

Tags: r, duplicates, unique, r-faq

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691369/how-can-i-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-in-php) for PHP, but I'm working with R and am unable to translate the solution to my problem.

I have this data frame with 10 rows and 50 columns, where some of the rows are absolutely identical. If I use unique on it, I get one row per - let's say - "type", but what I actually want is to get only those rows which only appear once. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I can have a look at clusters and heatmaps to sort it out manually, but I have bigger data frames than the one mentioned above (with up to 100 rows) where this gets a bit tricky.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This will extract the rows which appear only once (assuming your data frame is named `df`):

```
df[!(duplicated(df) | duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
```

*How it works*: The function `duplicated` tests whether a line appears at least for the second time starting at line one. If the argument `fromLast = TRUE` is used, the function starts at the last line.

Boths boolean results are combined with `|` (logical 'or') into a new vector which indicates all lines appearing more than once. The result of this is negated using `!` thereby creating a boolean vector indicating lines appearing only once.

Answer (score 12):

A possibility involving `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by_all() %>%
 filter(n() == 1)
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by_all() %>%
 filter(!any(row_number() > 1))
```

Since `dplyr 1.0.0`, the preferable way would be:

```
data %>%
    group_by(across(everything())) %>%
    filter(n() == 1)
```