# duplicates rows in R

Tags: r, rows, subset, duplicates

I am trying to subset a big dataset that I am working with in R. I normally use the `unique` command to get the dataset without the duplicates, according to the column A. Here I would like to do something a little different. I am looking forward to remove even the original row if it is a duplicate in the column A.
here's a sample of what the data looks like:

```
Name   A    B    C    D    E
JHA    2    45   2    32   20
OMI    2    49   5    321   5  
FIG    3    17   5    14   10
GJI    4    35   6    25   22
IJF    5    25   7    36   32
OPI    4    10   8    66   25
```

and I would like to make it look like this

```
Name  A    B    C    D    E
FIG   3    17   5    14   10
IJF   5    25   7    36   32
```

Is there a command that can do this in 1 go?

Many thanks,

Comment: Related: [*How can I remove all duplicates so that NONE are left in a data frame?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13763216/2204410)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` like this:

```
dat[!(duplicated(dat$A)| 
      duplicated(dat$A,fromLast=TRUE)),]
  A  B C  D  E
3 3 17 5 14 10
5 5 25 7 36 32
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
df[!df$A %in% df$A[duplicated(df$A)], ]
  Name A  B C  D  E
3  FIG 3 17 5 14 10
5  IJF 5 25 7 36 32
```

(or)

```
df[!with(df, A %in% A[duplicated(A)]), ]
```

(or)

```
df[with(df, setdiff(A, A[duplicated(A)])), ]
```

---

If you're interested in a `data.table` solution then, you could do:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[dt[, .I[.N == 1], by = A]$V1]
```