# How to keep rows without duplicate in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with many duplicated rows:

```
1    3
1    2
2    5
2    4
2    5
3    7
3    7
3    7
3    7
3    7
3    8
3    7
3    7
4    2 
4    5 
4    2
```

I want to keep just rows that repeat once in data.frame:

```
1    3
1    2
2    4
3    8
4    5
```

Would you please guide me?

Comment: `df[!(duplicated(df) | duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE)),]` should get 'er done

Comment: should be a duplicate of some topic ...

Comment: Found one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21831769/903061