# Select rows of data in dataframe that contain an element that isn't repeated (is unique)

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

Here's a test dataframe:

```
x = c("a", "b")
y = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6)
z = c(20,30,20,40,10,30,20,40)
Data = data.frame(x,y,z)
  x y  z
1 a 1 20
2 b 1 30
3 a 2 20
4 b 3 40
5 a 4 10
6 b 4 30
7 a 5 20
8 b 6 40
```

So there are two samples (a and b), and elements in y that could be unique for a or b or shared between them. I want to take out the rows of data that contain only the unique (not shared) y elements.

unique(Data$y) only gives me the list of all of the y values, with the duplicates removed. Instead, I want the full rows of only the y values that are not repeated within the dataframe. How do I do this?

EDIT: Expected output would be a dataframe containing only those rows which contain y values that are not repeated in the original dataframe (not shared between a and b)

```
  x y  z
1 a 2 20
2 b 3 40
3 a 5 20
4 b 6 40
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/21831769/903061 (for another duplicate).

Comment: Since it's a one-liner, the answer from the duplicate is `Data[!(duplicated(Data) | duplicated(Data, fromLast = TRUE)), ]`

Comment: Ah! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `duplicated` to index the dataframe.

```
Data[!duplicated(Data$y),]
```

gives

```
  x y  z
1 a 1 20
3 a 2 20
4 b 3 40
5 a 4 10
7 a 5 20
8 b 6 40
```

Comment: That basically does the same thing as unique though, and takes out the duplicate so that you're left with one of each of all of the y values. Instead, I want JUST those that are NOT repeated. So I want something to return just the rows with y values 2,3,5,6. (1 and 4 are repeated).