# How to identify only "not duplicated" rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a situation like this.
Multiple data.table "rbinded".

```
library(data.table)
x <-  data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4),dsp=c(5,6,7,8),status=c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE))
y <-  data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4),dsp=c(6,6,7,8),status=c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))
z <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4),dsp=c(5,6,9,8),status=c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE))
w <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4),dsp=c(5,6,7,NA),status=c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE))
setkey(x,id)
setkey(y,id)
setkey(z,id)
setkey(w,id)
Bigdt<-rbind(x,y,z,w)
```

I would like to obtain ONLY the not repeated rows like:

```
id  dsp status
1   6   FALSE
2   6   FALSE
3   9   FALSE
4   8   FALSE
4   NA  TRUE
```

So i tried

```
Resultdt<-Bigdt[!duplicated(Bigdt)]
```

but the result:

```
id  dsp status
1   5   FALSE
2   6   TRUE
3   7   FALSE
4   8   TRUE
```

does not match my espectations.
I tried in different methods (as rbind is not mandatory), for example merge, join etc. the data.table package seems potentially the one that contains the solution...apparently. Any ideas?

Comment: The code works fine for me (by copy pasting from here), Frank, sorry but your code does not give the espected result...

Comment: correct! Sorry, i will edit, but what about the other lines?

Comment: This is what I obtain: id dsp status N
    1   6  FALSE 1
    2   6  FALSE 1
    3   9  FALSE 1
    4   8  FALSE 1
    4  NA   TRUE 1

Comment: Here's the question for R in general, with an answer like one of @akrun's below http://stackoverflow.com/q/13763216/

Answer (score 9):

You can do

```
Bigdt[, .N, by=names(Bigdt)][N == 1L][, N := NULL][]

   id dsp status
1:  1   6  FALSE
2:  2   6  FALSE
3:  3   9  FALSE
4:  4   8  FALSE
5:  4  NA   TRUE
```

To see how it works, run just part of the `DT[][][][]` chain:

- `Bigdt[, .N, by=names(Bigdt)]`
- `Bigdt[, .N, by=names(Bigdt)][N == 1L]`
- `Bigdt[, .N, by=names(Bigdt)][N == 1L][, N := NULL]`

Comment: Thank you Frank! :)

Comment: If you hit memory limits with Frank's solution you can optionally use `dt[, N := rowidv(dt)]` to add sequence of duplicated rows to dataset in-place, then subset on `N==1L`.

Comment: @jangorecki The data table has to be sorted for that? I'll add it to the answer. Feel free to edit in any other details or alternatives.

Comment: @Frank no, see `rowidv(data.table(c("c","a","c","b","c","a")))`, it is extensively used in set operators using `all=TRUE` feature for handling duplicates. Just realized it won't answer the question as it lists all the unique rows instead - removing it from the answer then.

Answer (score 3):

You may also try

```
Bigdt[!(duplicated(Bigdt)|duplicated(Bigdt, fromLast=TRUE))]
#   id dsp status
#1:  1   6  FALSE
#2:  2   6  FALSE
#3:  3   9  FALSE
#4:  4   8  FALSE
#5:  4  NA   TRUE
```

Or if we are using `.SD`

```
Bigdt[Bigdt[,!(duplicated(.SD)|duplicated(.SD, fromLast=TRUE))]]
```

Or another option would be grouping by the column names, find the row index with `.I` and subset the dataset

```
Bigdt[Bigdt[, .I[.N==1], by = names(Bigdt)]$V1]
```