# dynamic ggplot layers in shiny with nearPoints()

Tags: r, ggplot2, reactive-programming, shiny

I'm familiar with the basics of shiny but struggling with something here. I would like to be able to add a ggplot layer when a point is clicked to highlight that point. I know this is possible with ggvis and there is a nice example in the gallery, but I would like to be able to use `nearPoints()` to capture the click as ui input.

I have tried something (see below) which works apart from the ggplot layer appears and then disappears. I have tried all kinds of edits to this with `reactive()`, `eventReactive()` and so on.

Any help is much appreciated...

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
        plotOutput("plot", click = "clicked")
    ),

  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_point(data = nearPoints(mtcars, input$clicked), colour = "red", size = 5)
    })
  })
)
```

I think I understand conceptually why this doesn't work. The plot has a dependency on `input$clicked` which means that when `input$clicked` changes the plot re-renders but this in turn resets `input$clicked`. Bit of a catch 22 situation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please, try this:

## Approach 1 (recommended)

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# initialize global variable to record selected (clicked) rows
selected_points <- mtcars[0, ]
str(selected_points)


shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    plotOutput("plot", click = "clicked")
  ),

  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    selected <- reactive({
      # add clicked
      selected_points <<- rbind(selected_points, nearPoints(mtcars, input$clicked))
      # remove _all_ duplicates if any (toggle mode) 
      # http://stackoverflow.com/a/13763299/3817004
      selected_points <<- 
        selected_points[!(duplicated(selected_points) | 
                            duplicated(selected_points, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
      str(selected_points)
      return(selected_points)
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_point(data = selected(), colour = "red", size = 5)
    })
  })
)
```

If you click a point one time it is highlighted. If you click it a second time the highlight is turned off again (toggling).

The code uses a global variable `selected_points` to store the actually highlighted (selected) points and an reactive expression `selected()` which updates the global variable whenever a point is clicked.

The `str(selected_points)` may help to visualize the working but can be removed.

## Approach 2 (alternative)

There is a slightly different approach which uses `observe()` instead of `reactive()` and references the global variable `selected_points` directly instead of returning the object from a function:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

selected_points <- mtcars[0, ]
str(selected_points)


shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    plotOutput("plot", click = "clicked")
  ),

  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    observe({
      # add clicked
      selected_points <<- rbind(selected_points, nearPoints(mtcars, input$clicked))
      # remove _all_ duplicates (toggle)
      # http://stackoverflow.com/a/13763299/3817004
      selected_points <<- 
        selected_points[!(duplicated(selected_points) | 
                            duplicated(selected_points, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
      str(selected_points)
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      # next statement is required for reactivity
      input$clicked
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_point(data = selected_points, colour = "red", size = 5)
    })
  })
)
```

Of course, you can use the global variable `selected_points` directly in the `ggplot` call instead of calling the reactive function `selected()`. However, you have to ensure that `renderPlot()` is executed whenever `input$clicked` is changed. Therefore, the dummy reference to `input$clicked` has to be included in the code within `renderPlot()`.

Now, the reactive function `selected()` is no longer needed and can be replaced by an `observe()` expression. As opposed to `reactive()`, `observe()` doesn't return a value. It just updates the global variable `selected_points` whenever `input$clicked` is modified.

## Approach 3 (reactive values)

This approach avoids a global variable. Instead, it uses `reactiveValues` to create a list-like object `rv`with special capabilities for reactive programming (see `?reactiveValues`).

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    plotOutput("plot", click = "clicked")
  ),

  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    rv <- reactiveValues(selected_points = mtcars[0, ])

    observe({
      # add clicked
      rv$selected_points <- rbind(isolate(rv$selected_points), 
                                           nearPoints(mtcars, input$clicked))
      # remove _all_ duplicates (toggle)
      # http://stackoverflow.com/a/13763299/3817004
      rv$selected_points <- isolate(
        rv$selected_points[!(duplicated(rv$selected_points) | 
                               duplicated(rv$selected_points, fromLast = TRUE)), ])
      str(rv$selected_points)
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_point(data = rv$selected_points, colour = "red", size = 5)
    })
  })
)
```

Please, note that in the `observer` part references to `rv` need to be encapsulated in `isolate()` to ensure that only changes to `input$clicked` will trigger execution of the code in `observer`. Otherwise, we'll get an endless loop. Execution of `renderPlot` is triggered whenever the reactive value `rv` is changed.

## Conclusion

Personally, I prefer approach 1 using reactive functions which make the dependencies (reactivity) more explicit. I find the dummy call to input$clicked in approach 2 less intuitive. Approach 3 requires a thorough understanding of reactivity and using `isolate()` in the right places.

Comment: thank you that's perfect. at first i could not understand why the second `geom_point` layer has the data source `selected()` but now I can see that the `selected()` function returns the `selected_points` object. out of interest, could i have `selected_points` as the data source and not return the object from the function? if so, why would you do it this way rather than the other?

Comment: Well, it's all about reactivity or what piece of code will be executed when a particular data is changed (reactivity). Yes, you can use `selected_points` but you have to enforce reactivity by adding a dummy call to `input$clicked` (see _Approach 2_ of my edited answer). I prefer to use reactive functions which make the dependencies more explicit.

Comment: Add-on question: How do you add a 'Reset' button to this interface which de-selects all selected points and allows user to start over with no points selected?

Comment: Answering my own question... Not sure this is correct, but I added a Reset button using Approach 3. Changing existing `observe` to `observeEvent(input$clicked, {...})` and adding `observeEvent(input$reset, { rv$selected_points <- mtcars[0,] })`  where `input$reset` is `actionButton("reset", "Reset Selection")` in the ui section.  Nice answer!