# Shiny update the clicked point to highlight it

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ropensci, ggplotly

Here is a working example of extracting the on-click event. I would like to ask you if there is a way to update the clicked point with either increase in size or highlight it etc.,?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
    plotlyOutput("plot"),
    verbatimTextOutput("click")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    nms <- row.names(mtcars)

    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, col = as.factor(cyl), key = nms)) + 
           geom_point()
        ggplotly(p)

    })

    output$click <- renderPrint({
        d <- event_data("plotly_click")
        if (is.null(d)) "Click events appear here (double-click to clear)" 
        else cat("Selected point associated with Car: ", d$key)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

*I have searched SO and other appropriate sources for finding a solution to the below question, but could not find one.*

**Update:**

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45969832/4836511) solution works better for this toy plot. But, my original use case contains 50+ levels for the variable of interest and there are high chances that Magenta or any other color would already be present. Also, it takes a considerable amount of time to change the color.
- Is there any way to increase the size of the clicked point to differentiate it from 100s of nearby points?

*A related question to change the shape of the clicked point has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45983949/4836511).*

Comment: There is a potentially related question ([dynamic ggplot layers in shiny with nearPoints()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40805513/3817004)) which doesn't involve `plotly`.

Comment: @Uwe Thanks, I will look into it. One main observation is `nearPoints()` does not work in case of  `ggplotly` plots. Secondly, as the entire plot is plotting again, it might be of opinion that the factor levels will get new colors and difficult to identify the selected region from the entire plot.

Answer (score 6):

You could add `Plotly`'s [events](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-events/) to your Shiny app with `htmlwidget`'s `onrender` function.

```
ggplotly(p) %>% onRender(javascript)
```

An array of `colors` is passed to the `restyle` function. The selected point (`pointNumber`) is colored magenta while the others get the color from the legend. You could do the same thing with the `marker` size, marker symbol is a bit more tricky because `Plotly` does not accept arrays here.

```
function(el, x){
  el.on('plotly_click', function(data) {
    colors = [];
    var base_color = document.getElementsByClassName('legendpoints')[data.points[0].curveNumber].getElementsByTagName('path')[0].style['stroke']
    for (var i = 0; i < data.points[0].data.x.length; i += 1) {
      colors.push(base_color)
    };
    colors[data.points[0].pointNumber] = '#FF00FF';
    Plotly.restyle(el, 
                   {'marker':{color: colors}}, 
                   [data.points[0].curveNumber]
                  );

  });
}
```

---

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

javascript <- "
function(el, x){
  el.on('plotly_click', function(data) {
    colors = [];

    var base_color = document.getElementsByClassName('legendpoints')[data.points[0].curveNumber].getElementsByTagName('path')[0].style['stroke']
    for (var i = 0; i < data.points[0].data.x.length; i += 1) {
      colors.push(base_color)
    };
    colors[data.points[0].pointNumber] = '#FF00FF';
    Plotly.restyle(el, 
                   {'marker':{color: colors}}, 
                   [data.points[0].curveNumber]
                  );
    //make sure all the other traces get back their original color
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('plotly')[0].data.length; i += 1) {
      if (i != data.points[0].curveNumber) {
        colors = [];
        base_color = document.getElementsByClassName('legendpoints')[i].getElementsByTagName('path')[0].style['stroke'];
        for (var p = 0; p < document.getElementsByClassName('plotly')[0].data[i].x.length; p += 1) {
          colors.push(base_color);
        }
        Plotly.restyle(el, 
                       {'marker':{color: colors}}, 
                       [i]);
      }
    };
  });
}"
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  nms <- row.names(mtcars)

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, col = as.factor(cyl), key = nms)) + 
      geom_point()
    ggplotly(p) %>% onRender(javascript)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Some explanations:

- Plotly's events, e.g. `plotly_click` pass some information (`data` in this case) in the event function
- `data.points` contains the points for which the event was triggered
- in this case, we only have one point `data.points[0]` where `pointNumber` is the index of the original array and `curveNumber` is the trace number.
- Plotly stores all the input data in the `div` where the plot is drawn
- We can access it via `document.getElementsByClassName('plotly')[0].data`
- The legend can be accessed via `document.getElementsByClassName('legendpoints')[i]` where `i` is the index of the legend
- ggplotly or plot_ly return htmlwidgets
- Javascript or HTML code can be added with any of the htmlwidget [functions](https://rdrr.io/cran/htmlwidgets/man/), e.g. `onrender` in this case

Comment: Thank you. It works brilliantly (+1). In my original use case, there are 50+ levels in the variable and there are very high chances that `magenta` will be one of them. In such a case, it will be difficult to identify the selected point. Do you think of any other options?  (A small typo in your answer `plotlyOutput("plot"),` comma should not be present).

Comment: Thanks for finding the leftover from the code edit! You could also change the size, e.g. `sizes.push(10);... sizes[...pointNumber] = 20;... 'marker': {size: sizes}`

Comment: (Forgot to ask another question I had in mind) Why is that I am able to highlight a point for each factor level? In the above plot, I am able to highlight at max three points (one each belonging to the `cyl==4`, `cyl==6`, `cyl==8`). I would like to highlight at max one point per point before it disappears to highlight next click point. What are your thoughts?

Comment: The proper way of doing it would be to restyle all traces/factors. In the example only the trace from the clicked point is restyled, I added the missing code to the example.

Comment: Could you please point me to the sources, from where I can understand your code and build up on the directions you have hinted? I would like to see what other components can be extracted and how they can be modified. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry but except for the link in the answer it was mostly trial and error, and reverse engineering. There is not a lot of detailed documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153354/discussion-between-prradep-and-maximilian-peters).

Comment: @Prradep please consider accepting this answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I have a follow up question, but for clarity I made a new SO post out of it. It involves adjusting your fantastic answer to work on scatter3d plotly objects. It is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365402/shiny-highlight-a-point-in-plotly-scatter3d

Comment: @MaximilianPeters, I was not able make your answer based on the to plotly bar plot. I just changed server section as follows: `plot_ly(x = c(1,2,3,4,5)) %>%
      add_bars( y = c(1,2,2.5,4,5), marker = list(color=c(rep('red',5))))  %>% onRender(javascript)` . The remaining part is same. Could you please let me know what am I missing.