# Keep only non-duplicated rows (and remove all others)

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I know this question has been asked in all sorts of variants, but I could not
extract the solution to my specific problem. Given a data frame like this:

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
df <-data.frame(a,b)
```

This results in:

```
 a b
1 A 1
2 A 1
3 A 2
4 B 4
5 B 1
6 B 1
7 C 2
8 C 2
```

I want to only keep row number 3 (A 2) and 4 (B 4).
I have tried all combinations of unique(), duplicated() and !duplicated() or
distinct, but could not get the desired result, since there seems to be no
combination of logical TRUE and FALSE that only filters out the non-duplicated rows. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts) gives you a hint, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the answer and sorry for the duplicate. I did not come across the first solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763216/how-can-i-remove-all-duplicates-so-that-none-are-left-in-a-data-frame) where the solution is: df[!(duplicated(df) | duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE)), ]

Comment: all good. No worries. :)