# How do I identify duplicates except for one column, and replace that column with max

Tags: r, max, tidyverse

I am trying to find data where three out of four columns are duplicated, and then to remove duplicates but keep the row with the largest number for the otherwise identical data.

I found [this very helpful article on the StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302683/select-all-rows-which-are-duplicates-except-for-one-column) which I think gets me about half way there.

I will base my question of the example in that question. (The example has more columns than what I am working on but I don' think that really matters.)

```
require(tidyverse)
x = iris%>%select(-Petal.Width)
dups = x[x%>%duplicated(),]
answer =  iris%>%semi_join(dups)

> answer 
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
2           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1    setosa
3           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1    setosa
4           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3    setosa
5           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
6           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3    setosa
7           5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
8           6.7         3.3          5.7         2.1 virginica
9           6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1 virginica
10          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.2 virginica
11          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
12          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
```

That article introduced me to code that will identify all rows where everything is equal except petal width:

```
iris[duplicated(iris[,-4]) | duplicated(iris[,-4], fromLast = TRUE),]
```

This is great but I don't know how to progress from here. I would like to have rows 2 and 5 to collapse into a single row that is equal to row 5. Similarly 9 & 10, should become just 10, and 8 & 12 become just 12.

The data set I have has more than 2 rows in some sets of duplicates, so I haven't had any luck using arrange functions to order them and delete the smallest row.

Comment: wouldn't this be `answer %>%
  group_by_at(-4) %>%
  slice(which.max(Petal.Width))` ? Also there are other matches as well. For example, row 1 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
iris %>%
   group_by(Sepal.Length,
            Sepal.Width,
            Petal.Length,
            Species) %>% 
   filter(Petal.Width == max(Petal.Width)) %>% 
   filter(row_number() == 1) %>% 
   ungroup()
```

The second filtering is to get rid of duplicates if the `Petal.Width` is also identical for two entries. Does this work for you?