# In R, remove all instances of a row with exactly n duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates, data-cleaning

I have a data frame in R with student grade data. Here's some sample data to show how it's structured:

```
student.data <- data.frame(
                 "CourseNumber" = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 105, 106, 106, 106),
                 "TermID" = c("T1", "E1", "S1", "T1", "E1", "S1", "T1", "S1", "T1", "E1", "S1", "S1", "T1", "E1", "S1"),
                 "StudentID" = c("9100", "9100", "9100", "9100", "9100", "9100", "9100", "9100", "9100", "9100", "9100", "8640", "8640", "8640", "8640"),
                 "Grade" = c(92, 80, 91, 83, 87, 84, 79, 79, 79, 85, 81, 98, 93, 97, 94))

student.data

##    CourseNumber TermID StudentID Grade
## 1           101     T1      9100    92
## 2           101     E1      9100    80
## 3           101     S1      9100    91

## 4           102     T1      9100    83
## 5           102     E1      9100    87
## 6           102     S1      9100    84

## 7           103     T1      9100    79
## 8           103     S1      9100    79

## 9           104     T1      9100    78
## 10          104     E1      9100    85
## 11          104     S1      9100    81

## 12          105     S1      8640    98

## 13          106     T1      8640    93
## 14          106     E1      8640    97
## 15          106     S1      8640    94
```

A single student will usually (but not always) receive 3 grades in a single course: S1, E1, and S1. That's why I've added extra breaks in the printout--each grouping of 3 represents a student's grade in a single course. T1 is his pre-exam score, E1 is his final exam score, and S1 is his post-exam score. The 3 are *supposed* to related by this formula `S1 = (80%)(T1) + (20%)(E1)`, and I'm finding instances where a higher S1 grade was awarded.

My problem is that I need to remove rows 7, 8, and 12 because those courses did not award all 3 grades (T1, E1, S1). This will help, because I already have some code that successfully calculates the amount of "bump" the teacher gave, but it throws an error every time it reaches a student-course combination that doesn't have all 3 grades (T1, E1, and S1).

So, my question is: how would I remove all rows for which there are not exactly 3 duplicates, as determined by the variables CourseNumber and StudentID? (A solution would work if it removes all rows for which there are *fewer* than 3 duplicates, or even if it just removed all rows for which there were exactly 2 duplicates.)

I found [this clever answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13763299/) and tried the code below, but it only removes rows for which there is no duplicate at all. So, it removes row 12 but doesn't also remove rows 7 and 8.

```
temp <- student.data[ , c("CourseNumber","StudentID") ]
student.data <- student.data[duplicated(temp) | duplicated(temp, fromLast = TRUE), ]

student.data

##    CourseNumber TermID StudentID Grade
## 1           101     T1      9100    92
## 2           101     E1      9100    80
## 3           101     S1      9100    91

## 4           102     T1      9100    83
## 5           102     E1      9100    87
## 6           102     S1      9100    84

## 7           103     T1      9100    79
## 8           103     S1      9100    79

## 9           104     T1      9100    78
## 10          104     E1      9100    85
## 11          104     S1      9100    81

## 13          106     T1      8640    93
## 14          106     E1      8640    97
## 15          106     S1      8640    94
```

Here's the output I'm trying to achieve:

```
##    CourseNumber TermID StudentID Grade
## 1           101     T1      9100    92
## 2           101     E1      9100    80
## 3           101     S1      9100    91

## 4           102     T1      9100    83
## 5           102     E1      9100    87
## 6           102     S1      9100    84

## 9           104     T1      9100    78
## 10          104     E1      9100    85
## 11          104     S1      9100    81

## 13          106     T1      8640    93
## 14          106     E1      8640    97
## 15          106     S1      8640    94
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description, the OP may need to return group that have 3 rows

```
library(dplyr)
student.data %>% 
   group_by(CourseNumber, StudentID) %>%
   filter(n() == 3) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
#   CourseNumber TermID StudentID Grade
#          <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
# 1          101 T1     9100         92
# 2          101 E1     9100         80
# 3          101 S1     9100         91
# 4          102 T1     9100         83
# 5          102 E1     9100         87
# 6          102 S1     9100         84
# 7          104 T1     9100         79
# 8          104 E1     9100         85
# 9          104 S1     9100         81
#10          106 T1     8640         93
#11          106 E1     8640         97
#12          106 S1     8640         94
```

Comment: Thanks!! I just added my expected output. This is exactly what I was looking for, including filter(n() == 3). Seeing the other examples you had shown were also really helpful. I'll accept this answer once the waiting period is complete!