# How to find duplicated values in column in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am having an issue extracting some rows from a data table.
I have a table as below.

What I try to do is extracting same "TEST_DATE" rows group by "ID"
For example, I want to get row number 8 and 9.

[image]

I used code below:

```
DUP_TEST_DATE <- SBP_VALUE[SBP_VALUE[, .I[duplicated(TEST_DATE)], by=ID]$V1]
```

However, this only returns the duplicated row (i.e., the row number 9 only).
Would you please help me to fix the code?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `duplicated(TEST_DATE) | duplicated(TEST_DATE, fromLast = TRUE))`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/13763216/680068