# PHP remove values from a single array?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove duplicate values from an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php)

How can I remove all multiple values for example 55,55 will only be 55 using PHP

Example 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 55
    [3] => 55
    [4] => 9
)
```

Example 1 should look like example 2 below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 55
)
```

Comment: duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from an array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
$a2 = array_unique($a);
```

Comment: You're **TWO seconds** faster!!!