# php foreach Loop try not to copy a array

Tags: php

Is there any way of not copying the specific array in the `foreach loop`? 
Here's the code

```
<?php

    $letters = array("A","B","B","C");

      foreach ($letters as $char){
        if ($char == "B") {
          continue; 
        }
        echo $char;
      }

?>
```

I want my output to be only `ABC` not `AC`

Comment: do you mean array_unique?

Comment: My advice: go read the manual, read a good book and practice. For the sake of not leaving my comment "empty": `echo implode(array_unique($letters));`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php

Answer (score 2):

You could strip non-unique elements first:

```
foreach(array_unique($letters) AS $char)
```

Comment: I see no sense in using loop for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
<?php

$letters = array("A","B","B","C");
  $letters = array_unique($letters);
  foreach ($letters as $char){        
       echo $char;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Also, `array_unique($letters)` should be `$letters = array_unique($letters);` `$letters` *isn't* being passed by reference as with `sort($letters)`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Sorry its just an typo...forgotted to put assigning

Answer (score 0):

To copy array use

```
$a = array("A","B","B","C");
$b = array_unique($a); // $b will be a different array with unique values
```

There is no need to use foreach. In PHP by default variables are not assigned by reference but by the value unless you use `&` operator.

The other way is to use `array_merge()`

```
$a = array("A","B","B","C");
$b = array();
$b = array_merge(array_unique($a), $b);
```

In both cases the result will be `A B C`