# How many i remove duplicates from this Array?

Tags: php

First i will like to say that, i have looked into other post but failed trying to accomplish my needs. I have used `array_unique($array)` but the duplicates don't get discarded. This is a view of my array using var_dump:

```
{
  [0]=>
  string(12) "44.94.192.40"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "44.94.192.41"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "44.94.1.1"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "44.94.1.1"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "44.96.253.100"
}
```

**"44.94.1.1"** is a duplicate which i hope to remove but i can't. Does this have to do with my array structure ?

Comment: How have you tried to remove it?

Comment: PHP doesn't have a built-in function named `array_split()`. You're probably looking for [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique).

Comment: Sorry i meant array_unique()

Answer (score 0):

**Edited in response to your comment:**

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/array_unique) on `array_unique()`:

> Two elements are considered equal if and only if `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2`. In words: when the string representation is the same.

So the fact that each of your values is an array is interfering.

Try creating an array containing just the string values:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $new_array[] = $value[0];
}
$new_array = array_unique($new_array);
```

Comment: Sorry i meant array_unique(); that what i have tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a foreach loop

```
$array = array(
  array("44.94.192.40"),
  array("44.94.192.41"),
  array("44.94.1.1"),
  array("44.94.1.1"),
  array("44.96.253.100"),
);
$temp_arr=array();
foreach($array as $elementKey => $element)
{
  foreach($element as $valueKey => $value)
  {
    if(in_array($value,$temp_arr)) unset($array[$elementKey]);
    else $temp_arr[]=$value;
  }
}
print_r($array);
```

Output would be:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 44.94.192.40 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 44.94.192.41 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 44.94.1.1 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 44.96.253.100 ) )
```

Comment: Because the OP has a multidimensional array, so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten your array and do array unique or do [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with a reference to a foreign array

```
<?php
$data = array(
  array("44.94.192.40"),
  array("44.94.192.41"),
  array("44.94.1.1"),
  array("44.94.1.1"),
  array("44.96.253.100"),
);

$visited = array();

array_map(function($v) use ( &$visited ){
   if(array_search( $v[0], $visited ) === false){
     $visited[] = $v[0];
   };
},$data);

var_dump($visited);

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "44.94.192.40"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "44.94.192.41"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "44.94.1.1"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "44.96.253.100"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a variety of ways to remove duplicates from a multidimensional array on the php doc page  of array_unique in the user comments

https://www.php.net/array_unique

Orel also mentioned a duplicate question that at a glance also contains a function for doing the same
[How to remove duplicate values from an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php)

For simplicity I have picked one for you,  but depending on exactly what you want,  there are many different flavors on the php page I linked

```
foreach ($arrAddressList AS $key => $arrAddress) {
    $arrAddressList[$key] = serialize($arrAddress);
}
$arrAddressList = array_unique($arrAdressList);
foreach ($arrAddressList AS $key => $strAddress) {
    $arrAddressList[$key] = unserialize($strAddress);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Rocket Hazmat for kindly editing the code snippet, I was struggling to format it from my phone browser