# Merge duplicates in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array generated daily that will have duplicate products in it.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 85
        [name] => Widescreen Espresso v6.1
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 85
        [name] => Widescreen Espresso v6.1
        [quantity] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 114
        [name] => Panama Esmerelda Diamond Mountain
        [quantity] => 1
    )
```

I want to find duplicate products and total them up in an array that would look like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 85
        [name] => Widescreen Espresso v6.1
        [quantity] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 114
        [name] => Panama Esmerelda Diamond Mountain
        [quantity] => 1
    )
```

---

UPDATE:

I didn't want to remove the duplicates I want to merge duplicates so that the quantity of the product is added together. I managed to work a solution to it with the help of Meenesh Jain's answer below.

```
           $final_array = array();
           foreach($order_data as $item => $item_value) {
               $pid = $item_value['product_id'];
               if(!isset($final_array[$pid])) {
                 $final_array[$pid] = $item_value;
               } else {
                 $final_array[$pid]['quantity'] += $item_value['quantity'];
               }
            }
            print_r(array_values($final_array));
```

Comment: you can do this via mysql query itself.

Comment: You can build another array. The index would be the product_id and the value the accumulated quantity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from an array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php)

Comment: I want to merge the duplicates so I get the quantity of each product added up not remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with **mysqli**

OR

you can apply a custom method on your array

```
 $temp_array = $new_array = array();
 foreach($array as $key => $arr_values){
   if(!in_array($arr_values['product_id'], $temp_array)){
         array_push($temp_array, $arr_values['product_id']);
         array_push($new_array,$array[$key]);
   } 
  }
```

// this code will do the trick

Comment: This did not work. It just removed the duplicates from in the $new_array.

Comment: i have tested it its working. the concept is simple. it will create a new array for the product id that are unique in the array or array

Comment: But I wanted to merge the duplicate items in the array so that the quantities of unique products are added together not remove them

Answer (score 0):

My try:

```
function newArray($oldarray){
    $newarray;
    $newarray[0] = $oldarray[0];
    $ids;
    $ids[0] = array($oldarray[0][product_id],0);
    for($i = 1; $i < count($oldarray);$i++){
        $add = true;
        for($x = 0; $x < count($ids);$x++){
            if($oldarray[$i][product_id] == $ids[$x][0]){
                $add = false;
                $newarray[$ids[$x][1]-1] = array($newarray[$ids[$x][1]-1][product_id],$newarray[$ids[$x][1]-1][name],$newarray[$ids[$x][1]-1][quantity]+$oldarray[$i][quantity]);
            }
        }
        if($add == true){
            $newarray[count($newarray)] = $oldarray[$i];
            $ids[count($ids)] = array($oldarray[$i][product_id],count($newarray));
        }
    }
    return $newarray;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this function (need to pass $array=name of array and $key as 'product_id'):

```
function super_unique($array,$key)

    {

       $temp_array = array();

       foreach ($array as &$v) {

           if (!isset($temp_array[$v[$key]]))

           $temp_array[$v[$key]] =& $v;

       }

       $array = array_values($temp_array);

       return $array;



    }
```

**Example :**

```
<?php
$vikas=array('0' => array
    (
        'product_id' => 85,
        'name' => "Widescreen Espresso v6.1", 
        'quantity' => 1
    ),

'1' => array
    (
        'product_id' => 85,
        'name' => "Widescreen Espresso v6.1",
        'quantity' => 2
    ),

 '2' => array
    (
        'product_id' => 114,
        'name' => "Panama Esmerelda Diamond Mountain",
        "quantity" => 1 
    )

    );


    function super_unique($array,$key)

{

   $temp_array = array();

   foreach ($array as &$v) {

       if (!isset($temp_array[$v[$key]]))

       $temp_array[$v[$key]] =& $v;

   }

   $array = array_values($temp_array);

   return $array;



}

//print_r(array_unique($vikas['product_id']));
$vik=super_unique($vikas,'product_id');
print_r($vik);

?>
```