# Is there a way to check if two of the same values are in one array

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine that you have this PHP code:`$array1 = array("henk", "jackson", "henk");`.
Is there a way to check if $array1 has two of the same values in it (in this case henk) and then make it delete one of them so one stays in the array?

Comment: [This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) should help you

Comment: Good luck, and for next time read how to ask and search before asking, because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php) is exactly the same question as yours.

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or heavily downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. You should [read this before you post your next one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is **[`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)**:

```
$array1 = array("henk", "jackson", "henk");
$array2 = array_unique($array1);
print_r($array2);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => henk
    [1] => jackson
)
```