# How to show only the non duplicated values of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and i want to show all values but dont wanna show the double values. I dont want to delete the double values with the array_unique() function. Can someone show me how to do it.

```
    foreach ($comTemperatures1 as $value) {
    //$y = "0";

    //$y++;
    $class = "TC " . $value;
    //if ($thermoStatus[$y] == '0' ) {
    echo"<td class=\"$class\" id=\"$class\">" . $temperatures[$value] . "</td>";
    //} else if ($thermoStatus[$y] == '6' ) {  
    //}
}

$comTemperatures1 = array('3' ,'3','4', '4');
```

It't not a duplicate question because i don't want to delete the values.

Comment: just work on a copy of your array : `$array_copy = $array;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Comment: `array_unique()` will return a **new** array, What do you mean by *'i want to show'* ?

Comment: With show i ment just a simple echo

Comment: If you want the unique values then use the one that is returned from `array_unique()` , and If you want all values then use the original array

Comment: If you provided a sample data that will help

Comment: Do i delete the double values if i used array_unique()?

Comment: @biangoole No ! `$array2 = array_unique($array1);` array 2 is unique but array 1 still has all values

Comment: see this [demo](https://eval.in/867620)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php)

Comment: No it isn't a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$original = array("red", "red", "blue");
$unique = array_unique($original);
print_r($original);
print_r($unique);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"red");
print_r(array_unique($a));
?>
```