# Delete a duplicate string appearing in all array elements

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

In Laravel I can return data from Google analytics to get most visited page with this command:

```
$FilterData =$this->parseResults($data)->pluck('url');
```

It will be return this URLs:

```
 [
    "/products/r4-04",
    "/products/r6-01",
    "/products/cu3-20",
    "/products/r4-51",
    "/products/zp-1",
    "/products/r5-31",
    "/products/cu3-64",
    "/products/cu6-01-1",
    "/products/cu6-01-2",
    "/products/r4-14",
    "/products/t4-74",
    "/products/cu-001",
    "/products/cu5-18",
    "/products/zp-8",
    "/products/td6-01",
    "/products/t4-14",
    "/products/c6-01"
]
```

Now I want to **remove** all `/products/` word from this and **find** the products by slug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove duplicate values from an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php)

Comment: no, cause i want to remove part of this, not duplicate records

Comment: I just noticed, but you used a misleading title, I updated your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just remove `/products/` from every array value, you can use `str_replace` for this:

```
$FilterData =$this->parseResults($data)->pluck('url');
$FilterDataNew = str_replace("/products/","",$FilterData);
var_dump($FilterDataNew);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$products =  [
    "/products/r4-04",
    "/products/r6-01",
    "/products/cu3-20",
    "/products/r4-51",
    "/products/zp-1",
    "/products/r5-31",
    "/products/cu3-64",
    "/products/cu6-01-1",
    "/products/cu6-01-2",
    "/products/r4-14",
    "/products/t4-74",
    "/products/cu-001",
    "/products/cu5-18",
    "/products/zp-8",
    "/products/td6-01",
    "/products/t4-14",
    "/products/c6-01"
];
function replace($product) {
   return str_replace('/products/', '', $product);  
}
$products = array_map('replace', $products);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to achieve the same.

Assuming your variable as `$products`

```
 $array =  str_replace('/products/', '', $products);
 dd($array);
```

Comment: No need `array_map`, only `str_replace` will work in this case