# How to count unique values in array and store in another array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am trying to gather together unique values in an array to be able to pass them to a new array so I can use the data to create a chart.

The data I have is as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-17
            [device] => 2
            [time] => 15:51:37
            [rfid] => 23641
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-17
            [device] => 2
            [time] => 15:52:20
            [rfid] => 5609
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-17
            [device] => 2
            [time] => 15:53:23
            [rfid] => 5609
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-17
            [device] => 2
            [time] => 16:02:44
            [rfid] => 5609
        )

)
```

What would I need to do to get an output such as the following:

```
[date]=> 2020-09-17
[device]=>2
[RFID]=> 5609 [Count]=> 3
[RFID]=> 23641[Count]=> 1
```

Or is this even possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: hint, grab all dates or device with array_column, make them unique with array_unique.. loop over them, use array search to pick out the items which match the date or device, either add a new item or append/update existing. what have you tried?

Comment: I had tried sizeof, and array_count but they would both just give me the count - not retaining the values of rfid

Answer (score 0):

I changed the array from associative to an indexed array and then looped through to count the unique keys, and then add the count if the key had already been set.

```
$arrLength=count($count);

            $elementCount=array();

             for($i=0;$i<=$arrLength-1;$i++){
                $key=$count[$i];

            if(isset($elementCount[$key])){
                $elementCount[$key]++;

            } else {
                $elementCount[$key]=1;
            }
   }
   print_r($elementCount);
    echo'</pre>';
```

Output as follows

```
Array
(
    [2020-09-17] => 4
    [15:51:37] => 1
    [2] => 4
    [23641] => 1
    [15:52:20] => 1
    [5609] => 3
    [15:53:23] => 1
    [16:02:44] => 1
)
```

This post helped :

[How to remove duplicate values from an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php)